# Math question derivatives?Help

Tags: derivatives

I have to find the derivative of $y=e^{-x/y}$..should I do this by taking the $\ln$ of both sides? Will that give me $y'$?

Comment: It would be useful if you could show us your effort...

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**:Try to take the derivative with respect to $x$ on both sides (use implicite differentiation):
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = e^{-x/y}\frac{d}{dx}(-x)y^{-1}.
$$
You would get
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -e^{-x/y}\left[y^{-1} - xy^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}\right].
$$
Now try to solve this for $\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dx}}$.

**Method 2**: You can indeed also first take a $\ln$ on both sides so that you get:
$$
\ln(y) = -\frac{x}{y} = -xy^{-1}.
$$
Again, take $\displaystyle{\frac{d}{dx}}$ on both sides and get
$$
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = -y^{-1}+xy^{-2}\frac{dy}{dx}.
$$
Using that $y = e^{-x/y}$ these two methods actually give the same answer.